# Handling dates with Regex in Apache Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

Assuming that field `time` looks like `2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` , `piggybank.jar` has been imported already , and command `EXTRACT` has been defined (DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT();) What's the best way to extract fields `year, month, day, hour, minute, second` ? That's what I have done so far:

```
data = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN(EXTRACT(time, '(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)T(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+).(\\s+)'))
        AS (
            year: int,
            month: int,
            day: int,
            hour: int,
            minute: int,
            second: int,
            tail: chararray
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Pig 0.11 you can use the DateTime type.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (date:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(date) AS date;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE GetMonth(date) as month;
```

You can use these functions here: [DateTime functions](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#datetime-functions)

If you're not working with 0.11 you can write a UDF or resort to the regex you posted.